# Unable to send JMeter token value as cookie

Tags: cookies, jmeter

0

I have issues running scripts that work fine on my laptop but not on Server VMs (Both Windows and Linux).

Some of the modules on the application I test communicates with the client through Cookies. bearer authentication token is expected to be sent with the request header as cookie when accessing these functionalities. These are mostly javascript events on the browser.

JMeter 5.3 on my laptop is successfully sending these cookie values with / in server name field to the application server and also get the successful HTML response. But on the Linux/Windows server, it gives illegal character error (rightly so).

I then decided to develop the scripts directly on Windows Server. When I remove and added / in the path instead of the host name, the cookie value (token) was not sent and the application server throws authentication error. If I add 2 forward slashes, it works for some endpoints it works with 3 forward slashes. ///. Some endpoints works with // and if you choose "Redirect Automatically" only. If you choose "Follow Redirects", the application again throws authentication error. The developers are blaming JMeter for incorrect request but are not giving me more information.

Also tried setting the CookieManager.save.cookies=true in jmeter.properties

Can someone please help with this weird JMeter behavior?

Thanks,
Partha

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about "Domain" field of the [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager):

[image]

then you can tell your developers that they should stop blaming JMeter for sending incorrect requests but they should rather read [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.1) followed by [RFC 1034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034#section-3.5), once done they should quit their developer jobs and become rickshaws.

If you want to know more how does JMeter handle cookies the best way is [enabling debug logging for the HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control" level="debug" />
```

and next time you start JMeter you will see way more information regarding cookies extraction and manipulation in the [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging).

Comment: Thanks. The issue is with the httprequest's "Server Name or IP" field and not "Domain" field in cookie manager. My cookie manager doesn't have any user defined parameters.

Comment: The logs show the following enty : Cookie: dXXX.logoutData=XXXoibnN3aCJ9; dXXX.jwtToken=XXXx5_cAKv2fD4, X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest] The request gets a <!--Timezone detection--> error when not used with XMLHttpRequest.  So The cookie is being sent properly. In short, the request is not accepted by the application if the cookie value is not sent (rightly so) and JMeter is not able to send the request if the / is not in Server Name or IP field. 
Could it be because of configuration issue with JVM or JDK on the server VMs?